# Dplyr giving wrong results

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I am using dplyr to summarise a dataset but it's giving wrong result. My code is as bekow :-

```
Raw_Grp<-Raw_data%>%dplyr::group_by(as.character(Raw_data$Gardu))
                  `%>%dplyr::summarize(Avg=mean(Raw_data$Age))
```

Below is the str :-

```
data.frame':    3016 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Kecamatan: chr  "CENGKARENG" "CENGKARENG" "CENGKARENG" "CENGKARENG" ...
 $ Age      : num  377 370 352 313 299 291 260 223 207 200 ...
```

Ideally I should get by group values but I am getting the total mean displayed in all the distinct groups. I have searched and tried maximum possibilities like creating a data.table but the same result. If I check the group by in excel or other toll it gives perfect results.
Please help

Comment: Remove the `Raw_data$` inside the `group_by` and `summarize`  It would be `Raw_data %>% group_by(Gardu) %>% summarise(Avg = mean(Age))`

Comment: Hi, Awesome!! It works as expected . Many Thanks !! Have been stuck here for 1.5 days. If there is an explanation to it it would be great to understand. My programming is at basic stage in R. Thanks Again!

Comment: `dplyr` uses so called "quoting-functions", which means you don't supply the column names as strings like you initially tried with `as.character`, but just as regular text and the function does the quoting for you, hence `group_by(Gardu)`. To understand `dplyr` and other packages in the `tidyverse`, I recommend reading at least a couple of chapters from R for Data Science: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use `Raw_data$columnname`, it extracts the entire column disrupting the `group_by` condition.  So, the syntax would be only the column names of the interested columns

```
library(dplyr)
Raw_data %>% 
     group_by(Gardu) %>% 
     summarise(Avg = mean(Age))
```

But, there are cases when we need the entire column.  For example, if we wanted to check how many elements of 'Age' within 'Gardu' are less than the whole 'Age' column values

```
Raw_data %>%
    group_by(Gardu) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(Age < .$Age))
```

#### data

```
Raw_data <- structure(list(Gardu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
Age = c(21L, 19L, 38L, 31L, 37L, 47L, 21L, 41L, 42L, 20L, 
34L, 25L, 37L, 37L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: What is meant by "the whole 'Age" column' when used in a logical expression? Did you mean "mean(.$Avg)"

Comment: @42-  It is just an example to show an expression that counts the number of values that are less than the values in the entire column grouped by 'Gardu'.  It can be done using other ways.

Comment: The problem was that I thought it would throw an error, but maybe you have tested it and it does make sense?

Comment: I'm also confused by your `Age < .$Age` example - seems like `Age` will get recycled and I'm don't see how the result would be meaningful.

Comment: @Gregor  Wouldn't this gives the same output as `sapply(split(Raw_data$Age, Raw_data$Gardu), function(x) sum(x < Raw_data$Age))`  Basically, that example was to show a case where they wanted to extract the whole column for some kind of comparison

Comment: Yeah - that seems like a `base` equivalent. I'm having trouble imagining when I would *want* to do that. But that's probably just lack of imagination on my part.